# Where to put central code in a Ranorex test suite?

Tags: ranorex

When executing the test suite, Ranorex runs the `Program` class. However, when running *Code Modules* individually in isolation, they appear to be executed directly.
I have code which I want to be executed in either case, but I cannot find a decent place to put it.

One option is to have *Code Modules* inherit from a base class which executes such code. Thereby, the base class code will be executed when a code module is run in isolation and also when it is run from within the test suite. However, this appears unintuitive, as I hijack the inheritance concept in order to solve an execution-order problem.